# Null static value from class inside WinRT background task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, uwp, winrt-component

I'm trying to save configuration(json string) passed from WinJs and read this configuration inside backgroundTask. I'm declaring static variable so I can read values from background Task but it returns null.

Class to store configuration:

```
public sealed class BackgroundTaskConfiguration
{
    internal static string jsonString;

    public static IList<Config> TileConfig { get; set; }

    public static void SaveTileConfig(string jsonConfig) {

        TileConfig = new List<Config>();
        jsonString = jsonConfig;

        JsonArray jsonArray;
        if (JsonArray.TryParse(jsonConfig, out jsonArray))
        {
            foreach (var item in jsonArray)
            {
                TileConfig.Add(Config.Create(item.GetObject()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static IList<Config> GetConfig() {
        return TileConfig;
    }
}
```

Then, I'm simply reading inside BackgroundTask method like

```
 var confg = BackgroundTaskConfiguration.TileConfig;
```

Or

```
var confg = BackgroundTaskConfiguration.GetConfig();
```

Both the lines  returns `null`.
Any clue what is not correct here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're calling `SaveTileConfig` in your front end, and expect the static value to be available in the background task automatically?

That's unfortunately not how it works. See background tasks and main app as different programs which run in different contexts. They only have in common that they run on the same device and in the same folder.

The solution is to serialize and save your `TileConfig` in some file and then load and deserialize it in the background task. There's no other way to share data between bg task + foreground app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate memory for **TileConfig**. If you call

```
var confg = BackgroundTaskConfiguration.GetConfig();
```

after call method: **SaveTileConfig**, then will be not null.
You allocate memory in method **SaveTileConfig** for property **TileConfig**.